# How to gzip the resulting output of an awk command?

Tags: bash, awk, gzip

I tried this but it did not work. How can I generate the output to be a gz file from an awk command?

```
 awk -v someVariable="$VAR1" '
        BEGIN {
         . . .
        }

        {
           SOME CODES HERE
        }
        END {}
    ' $FILES> gzip $RESULTING_OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 5):

You can EITHER pipe your output to gzip outside of awk (as Tom suggested), or you can send output through pipes from *inside* awk.  Like this:

```
awk '
  {
    print | "gzip > /path/to/output.gz";
  }
' inputfile
```

This has a tremendous advantage in certain situations.  For example, if you want to split a really long log file into hourly chunks, you can build your output command as a variable, then pipe to the variable.

```
awk '

  # given:
  #   Mar 20 13:29:12 servername some message

  BEGIN {
    m["jan"]="01"; m["feb"]="02"; m["mar"]="03"; m["apr"]="04"; 
    m["may"]="05"; m["jun"]="06"; m["jul"]="07"; m["aug"]="08"; 
    m["sep"]="09"; m["oct"]="10"; m["nov"]="11"; m["dec"]="12";
  }

  {
    output=sprintf("gzip -9 > /var/log/split/%s-%s-%s.log.gz", m[tolower($1)], $2, substr($3,1,2));
    print | output
  }' input.log
```

With this usage, your output gzip command line is re-evaluated for every line of input, and awk *doesn't close the pipe* unless it's told to manually, or awk runs out of input and exits.

My own use case for this was that we were gathering web server logs from a CDN that were not in chronological order.  The logs were way too large for `sort`, but could be handled when split into hourly chunks.

YMMV.  The best solution depends on what you're actually trying to achieve, which you haven't told us.

Answer (score 3):

You need to *pipe* the output to `gzip`, *then* redirect then output to a file:

```
awk '...' $FILES | gzip > "$RESULTING_OUTPUT"
```

Note that capital letters for variables names are not recommended, as they may clash with shell internal variables. Also, `$FILES` looks suspiciously like it may contain a list of more than one file name. You should really be using an array, which you can pass like `"${files[@]}"`

Answer (score 0):

This worked

```
 awk -v someVariable="$VAR1" '
            BEGIN {
             . . .
            }

            {
               SOME CODES HERE
            }
            END {}
        ' $FILES> $RESULTING_OUTPUT
    gzip $RESULTING_OUTPUT
```